# Input change function doesn't trigger - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `dropdown` and a `textbox`.

I'm passing the dropdown value to a textbox.

And the dropdown I've created using `jquery.dropdown`. And so I can't directly write a function like `$('.dropdown').change(function() {})`.

Now I wanted to write a function on textbox change.

I tried few functions. But nothing helped me out.

It only works if I manually type or press enter while focused on the textbox.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SPx7/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programatically changing a value does not trigger events, only user interaction does that.
You'd have to trigger the event yourself

```
$("input[name='textbox']").val(value).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6SPx7/1/)

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot. That helped me out. So the values generated or passed progrmatically does not trigger any events. Thanks again. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use change function to trigger the event:

```
$('.dropdown').change(function() {

    $("input[name='textbox']").val(this.value).change()
})
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6SPx7/3/) Is your updated script